# Can I debug into lambdas/delegates in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates, .net-6.0

I'm having trouble finding a clear answer on this and I'm able to place a breakpoint on

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(hostBuilderContext.Configuration["BaseUrl"]);
```

...should I be able to debug into this lambda and inspect the values being set? I expected to be able to hit that line using step into. My debugger just steps over it to the return statement.

```
    public IServiceCollection AddServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, FunctionsHostBuilderContext hostBuilderContext)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddHttpClient<IMyInterface, MyClass>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(hostBuilderContext.Configuration["BaseUrl"]);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Api-Key", hostBuilderContext.Configuration["APIKey"]);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Use-Raw", "false");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        });

        return serviceCollection;
```

Comment: You can't step into it during _initialization_ because it is registering a callback. You should set a breakpoint and you'll see that the callback is called later in the initialization pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to debug this line when you call your final point, that is, when you post or you will probably be able to debug this line, leave your breakpoint marked